# Socket receive hangs in .NET 4.5 under windows 2012

Tags: .net, postgresql, windows-server-2012, npgsql

We have a web application that is built around NHibernate and the Npgsql provider, which has been working fine on server 2008 R2 and .NET 4. We have now upgraded to Server 2012 and the 4.5 stack, and are experiencing weird hangs in the database layer.

We have threads that will freeze forever on my test server (virtual instance of server 2012), and that hangs approx 7.5 or 15 minutes (450 sec or 900 sec, approx) on the production servers (I only know this because it will usually tell in the logs).

When I manage to reproduce this on my testservice, and attach a debugger, I see that one thread will be in the following state:

```
[Managed to Native Transition]   
System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags socketFlags, out System.Net.Sockets.SocketError errorCode)  
System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)    
mscorlib.dll!System.IO.BufferedStream.ReadByte()     
Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlState.ProcessBackendResponses_Ver_3.MoveNext()   
Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextResponseObject()     
Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextRowDescription()     
Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.NextResult()    
Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.ForwardsOnlyDataReader(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Npgsql.IServerResponseObject> dataEnumeration, System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior, Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand command, Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.NotificationThreadBlock threadBlock, bool synchOnReadError)     
Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.GetReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior cb)    
Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteBlind()   
Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlTransaction.Rollback()   
NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Rollback()
```

In the postgres end, I also see a running query, but I guess that is because the transaction is never rollbacked. We are using Npgsql v2.0.12 (the latest stable).

What could be the cause for this hang, and this extremely long timeout (or lack of timeout in test)? And why would it differ on different OS?

We did run this on server 2008 R2 with .NET 4.5 on one server before, and never saw this behavior either. But I assume that since this is a Native call, it is OS dependent?

Does anyone has any theory to why this would happen?

Comment: I suggest seeing what, if anything, is happening on the server side. Are the queries waiting on a lock (`waiting = t` in `pg_stat_activity`; details in `pg_locks`)? On Linux I'd attach gdb and see if the server was waiting to receive data from the client too; in this case it'd strongly suggest an nPgSQL bug. Doing that on Windows is more fiddly and difficult unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There are no locks, and the relevant query is usually just en empty result set (takes no time to execute). It is the same DB-server that was used with server 2008 R2 where we had no trouble like this (it probably hang as well, but did timeout in a timely manner). I mean, a socket which has an endpoint that has died for some reason, should be handled at some point, right?

Comment: With your stackstrace, looks like a bug in Npgsql.dll which does not correctly set whatever timeout it should set, or has an incompatibility with the 2012 network stack. In 2012, there is a new notion of "blocked network". For example requests to 127.0.0.1 are all refused by default for non administrators ... So maybe you should give more rights to the user running your app. Try giving it administrator rights to see if it is this kind of problem, then you could fine grained your user's rights.

Comment: @Softlion That's interesting, do you have any link about it? We do however not do any loopback connections, but I agree that it might be an underlying bug in Npgsql. I have searched through the documentation regarding timeouts but haven't found anything. However, it has worked before in 2008, so I'm wondering if there are some defaults that has changed with 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Things to check in order:

1. Locks on the server side.
2. Network interruption and timeout.
3. Responsiveness on the server.
4. Long-running queries.